# Running calculation over two another column

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a `balance` column `over (partition by add subtract) order by Date` as below

```
ID       Date          Add    Subtract    Balance
a     2019/01/01       500      0           500
a     2019/01/02        0      300          200
b     2019/03/01       800      0           800
b     2019/03/10       300      0          1100
```

I saw the solution once, but can not find it again. According to my remember, we need `coalesce`, `lag`, `lead`.

Pls help or give me a link to the relate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the data you have, you need only the `sum()` window function:

```
select *, 
       sum(add - subtract) 
         over (partition by id 
                   order by date) as balance
  from your_table
```